# suspect result with std::map insert

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

I tried to use:

```
std::map<std::wstring, std::pair<std::wstring, INT_PTR>> mm;
**mm.insert(_T("name"), std::make_pair(_T("value1"), static_cast<INT_PTR>(1));**
```

What is wrong with that?

If I use this:

```
mm[_T("name")] = std::make_pair(_T("value1"), static_cast<INT_PTR>(1));
```

it works.

The error is this:

```
No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

The same with that:

```
std::map<std::wstring, std::vector<std::pair<std::wstring, INT_PTR>>> mm;

std::vector <std::pair<std::wstring, INT_PTR>> vec;
vec.push_back(std::make_pair(_T("value1"), static_cast<INT_PTR>(1)));
mm.insert(_T("name"), vec);
```

Why does it work with "insert_or_assign" like this?

```
mm.insert_or_assign(_T("name"), vec);
```

Comment: Try `emplace` instead of `insert`. It directly forwards to constructor of `pair`.

Answer (score 5):

[std::map::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) simply doesn't take the two parameters that you're attempting. It takes a one-parameter key-value pair.

```
mm.insert(std::make_pair(_T("name"), std::make_pair(_T("value1"), static_cast<INT_PTR>(1))));
```

[std::map::insert_or_assign](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign) on the other hand does take the two parameters you're attempting.

Comment: This error messages from stl often confuse me, thanks.